# react-virtualized Data Table Example

Tags: reactjs, datatable, ecmascript-6, babeljs, react-virtualized

I am attempting to implement a simple data table as shown by the author's example here: [example](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/Table/Table.example.js)

```
...
export default class TableExample extends Component {
static contextTypes = {
list: PropTypes.instanceOf(Immutable.List).isRequired
};
...
```

I've tried to pass in an ImmutableJS List as a property to no avail. Is there something else I'm missing here?

How do you get the data array into the component?

My parent component which renders the table example looks like this:

```
  render() {
  const list = fromJS(this.props.data);
  console.log(typeof(list)); //this outputs "object"
  console.log(list); // this outputs ImmutableJS list with size of 761
  return (
     <TableExample list={list}/>
     )
  }
```

I've also tried to change all declarations of { list } in the TableExample linked from this.context to this.props without much success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Console error returned by Chrome at this point:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for                  
built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but     
got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the               
file it's defined in. Check the render method of `TableExample`.
```

Comment: Provide a Plnkr repro and I'll take a look. Seems like maybe you're importing `Table` from react-virtualized incorrectly or something. Depending on how exactly you copied my example, it may be because you need to change `import Table from './Table'` to `import { Table } from 'react-virtualized'`

Comment: @brianvaughn I wasn't sure how to include the Plnkr with react -- I've linked a pastebin with my table which is identical to the table you are providing in your example: http://pastebin.com/LG8bXM76

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lines are problematic:

```
import { ContentBox, ContentBoxHeader, ContentBoxParagraph } from 'react-virtualized';
import { LabeledInput, InputRow } from 'react-virtualized';
```

Those components are used in the react-virtualized demo site. They are not packaged with the react-virtualized NPM dist (so you can't import them). This is the cause of the error message you pasted above:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to
>   export your component from the file it's defined in.
>   Check the render method of `TableExample`.

There may be additional problems; I didn't read too closely after noticing the bad imports.

Comment: thanks so much for your help here -- this only became clear for almost two days after using your lib -- hopefully this question helps people define the line between lib components and custom for demo purposes

Comment: So how are you supposed to use your table? Why are all the parts not in the npm lib? I really suggest you to add live examples that don't rely on local implementations imports but are stand alone, like the examples of `react-table`.

Comment: "So how are you supposed to use your table?" Read the docs. There are examples (with code) in them.

Sorry for the somewhat short response, but... I spent a lot of time writing the docs. https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Table.md

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the author has included a style sheet which may or may not be rendering correctly in your attachment. Subsequently, all content from lines 74-162 in the author's source Table example will fail to render which in turn cascades through the render function breaking the component.

You can resolve this issue and verify it by removing lines 74-162 and the final  closing tag on line 217. After reloading, you should be then greeted with a basic table.

Your approach to providing the data array is correct and does result in the appropriate rendering.

Cheers to [@brianvaughn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1123805/brianvaughn) and his fantastic work